# How to subtract columns in a multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a multiindex dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ind1': list('aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb'),
                   'ind2': list('cccdddeeecccdddeee'),
                   'ind3': list(range(3))*6,
                   'val1': list(range(100, 118)),
                   'val2': list(range(70, 88))})

df_mult = df.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2', 'ind3'])

                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
     d    0      103    73
          1      104    74
          2      105    75
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0      109    79
          1      110    80
          2      111    81
     d    0      112    82
          1      113    83
          2      114    84
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

What I want to do is to subtract the values in `df_mult.loc['a', 'e', :]` and `df_mult.loc['b', 'e', :]`, respectively from the values corresponding to `df_mult.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :]` and `df_mult.loc['b', ['c', 'd'], :]`, respectively. The expected outcome would be

```
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -5
          1       -3    -5
          2       -3    -5
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -3
          1       -3    -3
          2       -3    -3
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

Ideally, something like this would work

```
df_mult.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :].subtract(df_mult.loc['a', 'e', :])
```

but this gives me a lot of `NaNs`.

How would I do this?

Comment: Is this Python-2.x?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE2:** with [kind help of @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46594589/5741205):

```
def repeat_blocks(a, repeats=2, block_length=None):
    N = a.shape[0]
    if not block_length:
        block_length = N//2
    out = np.repeat(a.reshape(N//block_length,block_length,-1),
                    repeats,
                    axis=0) \
            .reshape(N*repeats,-1)
    return out

In [234]: df_mult.loc[idx[['a','b'], ['c', 'd'], :], :] -= repeat_blocks(df_mult.loc[['a','b'], 'e', :].values)

In [235]: df_mult
Out[235]:
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3
a    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -3
          1       -3    -3
          2       -3    -3
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -3
          1       -3    -3
          2       -3    -3
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [100]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [102]: df_mult.loc[idx['a', ['c', 'd'], :], :] -= \
              np.concatenate([df_mult.loc['a', 'e', :].values] * 2)

In [103]: df_mult
Out[103]:
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3
a    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -3
          1       -3    -3
          2       -3    -3
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0      109    79
          1      110    80
          2      111    81
     d    0      112    82
          1      113    83
          2      114    84
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

**Old (incorrect) answer:**

```
In [62]: df_mult.loc['a', 'e', :] -= df_mult.loc['b', 'e', :].values

In [63]: df_mult
Out[63]:
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3
a    c    0      100    70
          1      101    71
          2      102    72
     d    0      103    73
          1      104    74
          2      105    75
     e    0       -9    -9
          1       -9    -9
          2       -9    -9
b    c    0      109    79
          1      110    80
          2      111    81
     d    0      112    82
          1      113    83
          2      114    84
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response; I might miss something but this does not look like the desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry for being not precise enough. For each value in `ind1`, I want to subtract all values corresponding to `e` (in `ind2`) from all the remaining values in `ind2`. E.g. `(a, c, 0)=100` - `(a, e, 0)=106` would be `-6` (see my desired outcome in the question). Same then for `(a, c, 1)=101` - `(a, e, 1)=107` is also `-6` and so on. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: That looks good, indeed (upvoted).  Is there an easy way to do the same for `b` in the same go for `a` or would I have to loop through all elements in `ind1`?

Comment: Update 2 gives a wrong result for `b`(`3` instead of `-6`) and also for `a` (the `-12` is incorrect).

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like ? (`df` here equal `df_mult`)

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx['a', ['c', 'd'], :],idx['val1','val2']]=df.loc['a', ['c', 'd'], :].values-np.tile(df.loc['a', 'e', :].values, (2, 1))

df
Out[608]: 
                val1  val2
ind1 ind2 ind3            
a    c    0       -6    -6
          1       -6    -6
          2       -6    -6
     d    0       -3    -3
          1       -3    -3
          2       -3    -3
     e    0      106    76
          1      107    77
          2      108    78
b    c    0      109    79
          1      110    80
          2      111    81
     d    0      112    82
          1      113    83
          2      114    84
     e    0      115    85
          1      116    86
          2      117    87
```

Comment: yeah, we've posted it at the same time ;-) +1

Comment: @MaxU thanks dude, I already upvoted yours, when i saw you answer , I you show the key to solve the problem .

Comment: That seems to work, thanks (upvoted)!  Is there an easy way to do the same for `b` in the same go for `a` or would I have to loop through all elements in `ind1`? Also, is there a way to avoid `idx['val1','val2']` as I have a lot of columns?

Comment: @Cleb, so far right now ,I can only provide the `for` loop method , like `for x,df in df.groupby('ind1'): `

Comment: @Cleb and I think MaxU already provide a nice way for achieve this

Comment: @Wen: Yes, that's why I upvoted both answers; but if there is even a way to avoid the loop it would be even better :)