# Fast numpy way to repeat (vertically) each half of 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming we have the following 2D array:

```
In [200]: a = np.arange(8).reshape(4,2)

In [201]: a
Out[201]:
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

How may repeat each half of it, so I have the following 2D array:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],  # second half 
       [6, 7],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

My attempt produces wrong result:

```
In [202]: np.tile(np.split(a, 2), 2).reshape(-1,2)
Out[202]:
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape to split the first axis into two giving us a 3D array, then repeat along the first and finally reshape back to 2D -

```
np.repeat(a.reshape(-1,2,2),2,axis=0).reshape(-1,2)
```

Generalizing it -

```
def repeat_blocks(a):
    N = a.shape[0]
    B = N//2 # Block length
    R = 2 # number of repeats
    out = np.repeat(a.reshape(N//B,B,-1),R,axis=0).reshape(N*R,-1)
    return out
```

Sample runs -

Case #1 :

```
In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])

In [121]: repeat_blocks(a)
Out[121]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
```

Case #2 :

```
In [123]: a
Out[123]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])

In [124]: repeat_blocks(a)
Out[124]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
```